# nobody and nogroup as directory owner when writing with php

Tags: apache2, php

When executing a php script, that creates a directory the resulting file is owned by `nobody` and `nogroup`. I know that apache2 is executed as `www-data` on Ubuntu systems, so, why is my directory owned by `nobody`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even though nobody and nogroup sounds special, they are more or less a regular system user (`nobody`) and a regular system group (`nogroup`), much like `www-data`

When your created files have these owners, then most likely your php is executed as `nobody` instead of `www-data`. Check you webserver configuration. It might be possible, that apache is run as `nobody`, or, more likely, that you use some kind of cgi/fastcgi setup (like mod_fastcgi or a `php5-fpm`.